Does open bim component have context menu in?
Can you tell me please. Does open bim component have context menu in? So that the context menu opens, when we pushed right button of mouse on mesh.  Any help and pointers to sources appreciates. How do you make your contextmenu on your projects? Share please with me! Thank you very much advanced!
